# Asp.net MVC Compiler Error Message: CS1061:

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, pagination

I am adding pagination in my project after adding all the code it show following error.

> Compiler Error Message: CS1061:
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' does
>   not contain a definition for 'Pagination' and no extension method
>   'Pagination' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' could
>   be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

**View:**

```
<h2
Online Store
</h2>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{

<div style="display:inline-block">
    <div style="width:30%; float:left;">
        <img src="@item.Image" width="170" height="276"             alt="@item.ProductName" title="@item.ProductName">
    </div>
    <div style="width:70%; float:left;">

        <h3>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductName)
        </h3>

        <p>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
        </p>

        <p>
            $@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
        </p>

        <p>
            @Html.ActionLink("More Info", "Index", "ItemDetail", new { id = item.ProductID }, new { id = "ProductID" })
        </p>

    </div>

</div> }
<div class="pager">
@Html.PageLinks(Model.Pagination, x => Url.Action("Index", new { page = x         }))
```

**Model:**

```
namespace ISkills.Models
{
public class PaginationModel
{

    public int TotalItems { get; set; }
    public int ItemsPerPage { get; set; }
    public int CurrentPage { get; set; }

    public int TotalPages
    {
        get { return (int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)TotalItems / ItemsPerPage);    }

    }
```

**Controller:**

```
private ISkillsContext db = new ISkillsContext();
    private const int PAGE_SIZE = 3;


    public ActionResult Index( int page =1)
    {
        var data = db.Products.Select(p => p)
            .OrderBy(p => p.ProductName)
            .Skip((page - 1) * PAGE_SIZE).Take(PAGE_SIZE);

        ProductsModel model = new ProductsModel
        {
            Products = data,
            Pagination = new PaginationModel
            {
                CurrentPage = page,
                ItemsPerPage = PAGE_SIZE,
                TotalItems = db.Products.ToList().Count()
            }
        };
```

**HTML Helper:**

```
namespace ISkills.HtmlHelpers
{
public static class PaginationHelper
{
    public static MvcHtmlString PageLinks(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
                                         PaginationModel pagination,
                                         Func<int, string> pageUrl)
    {

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 1; i <= pagination.TotalPages; i++)
        {
            TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("a");
            tag.MergeAttribute("href", pageUrl(i));
            tag.InnerHtml = i.ToString();
            if (i == pagination.CurrentPage)
            {
                tag.AddCssClass("selected");
                tag.AddCssClass("btn-primary");
            }
            tag.AddCssClass("btn btn-default");
            result.Append(tag.ToString());
        }
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(result.ToString());
    }
}
}
```

**Can any one help me, How to resolve this error ?**

Comment: Please add the rest of your `Index` method of your controller. Also, is the view actually a partial view?

Comment: Are you using @model IEnumerable<YourModelName> in your viewpage?